# Azure Data Factory .NET SDK activity metrics

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring

Does anyone know how to (or if it possible) to access these metrics for each activity run shown under "Details" in the Azure Portal?

[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

The initial plan was to use the .NET SDK but none of these metrics seems to be included. This is what I have managed to find so far.

```
var datasliceRunListResponse = client.DataSliceRuns.List(
                _resourceGroupName,
                dataFactoryName,
                Dataset_Destination,
                new DataSliceRunListParameters()
                {
                    DataSliceStartTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.ConvertToISO8601DateTimeString()
                }
            );

        foreach (DataSliceRun run in datasliceRunListResponse.DataSliceRuns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: \t\t{0}", run.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceStart: \t{0}", run.DataSliceStart);
            Console.WriteLine("DataSliceEnd: \t\t{0}", run.DataSliceEnd);
            Console.WriteLine("ActivityId: \t\t{0}", run.ActivityName);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingStartTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessingEndTime: \t{0}", run.ProcessingEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage: \t{0}", run.ErrorMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Has logse: \t\t{0}", run.HasLogs.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Id: \t\t\t{0}", run.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Log uri: \t{0}", run.LogUri);
            Console.WriteLine("Properties: \t{0}", run.Properties.Count);

        }
```

Comment: Just checked the PowerShell cmdlets Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow and Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun. They don't include this level of detail. Yet!

Comment: Have you raised an MS connect item for this?

Comment: Have done some more digging in this and it is actually possible with the .NET SDK but you need to do a two step fetch. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found the solution in the .NET SDK. You need to do a "two step fetch".

**Get slice details**

[image]

```
DateTime PipelineActivePeriodStartTime;
    DataSliceRunListResponse sliceList = new DataSliceRunListResponse();
    DataSliceRunGetResponse sliceResponse = new DataSliceRunGetResponse();
    PipelineActivePeriodStartTime = new DateTime(2017, 3, 20, 07, 00, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(_aadTokenCredentials, _resourceManagerUri);

    sliceList = client.DataSliceRuns.List(
                _resourceGroupName,
                _dataFactoryName,
                _datasetDestination,
                new DataSliceRunListParameters()
                {
                    DataSliceStartTime = PipelineActivePeriodStartTime.ConvertToISO8601DateTimeString()
                }
    );

    foreach (DataSliceRun run in sliceList.DataSliceRuns)
    {
        sliceResponse = client.DataSliceRuns.Get(_resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, run.Id.ToString());

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in sliceResponse.DataSliceRun.Properties)
        {
            switch (entry.Key.Trim())
            {
                case "rows":
                    rows = Convert.ToInt32(entry.Value);
                    break;
                case "dataRead":
                    dataRead = entry.Value;
                    break;
                case "dataWritten":
                    dataWritten = entry.Value;
                    break;
                case "throughput":
                    throughtput = entry.Value;
                    break;
                case "totalDuration":
                    totalDuration = entry.Value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```