# Azure Data Factory Activity Attempts using PowerShell

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any way to get information from Activity Attempts using PowerShell? I need following info:
[Attempts window in Azure Data Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWSOg.jpg)

I have tried using Get-AzureRmDataFactoryActivityWindow and Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun, but fields like "Data read", "Data written" and "Rows" are not available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Data Factory .NET SDK activity metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681054/azure-data-factory-net-sdk-activity-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this from PowerShell. But you can get it using the Azure .Net SDK.

Check out this question:

[Azure Data Factory .NET SDK activity metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681054/azure-data-factory-net-sdk-activity-metrics)